# Script in Groovy to update and insert Initial_Range and Final_Range

Tags: java, sql, groovy, helper

### Im new on Groovy and need some help.

I have that table called RANGE with :

```
ID_RANGE - Integer
Year - Integer
six_Month - Integer
Initial_Range - String
Final_Range - String
Last_Update - TimeStamp
```

---

I have to do a script to update/insert Initial_Range and Final_Range.
I will receive the new data from a map called "df_map" with the following data:

```
df_map.Update_date -> String
df_map.six_Month -> Integer
df_map.Initial_range -> String (Format "AA-123456678")
df_map.Final_range -> String (Format "AA-123456678")
```

---

That script have to validate some requirements,
if it doesn't, it can´t continues:

- the date have to be a valid timeStamp (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS)
- there must be 1000 values ​​between Initial_Range and Final_Range
- Only can update or insert a future date

When check all this, have to search if the register to modify exits, if not exits, have to create it.

that script has helpers to do 2 actions:

- sqlQuery -

Make a query against the bbdd and show and array with the data. It get parameters like bbdd,query and parameters maps.

EXAMPLE:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM RANGE WHERE ID_RANGE = :RANGE"
params = [:]
params.RANGE = 1
outcome = sqlQuery(bbdd,query,params)
```

-sqlUpdate -

It make an insert or an update against the database and returns an array with the result. It receives as parameters the database, query, parameter map.

EXAMPLE:

```
query = "UPDATE RANGE SET Initial_Range = :Initial_Range WHERE ID_RANGE = :RANGE"
params = [:]
params.RANGE = 1
outcome = sqlUpdate(bbdd,query,params)
```

---

I work with sql but never before with groovy.....
Thanks in advance ;)